# Anchored snapper

Tags: distance, gps, fme-form, snapping, fme-transformer

If you have seen the image, the labels displayed near the points they mention the order or the route of GPS, I would like to know is there a possibility for example to eliminate the segment which is near point 70, because in real life it should snap on the other segment.[image]

Answer (score 1):

It's hard to do this in an automatic way unless you can specify exactly why that segment should be removed. We need some form of rule to define it.

For example, you could measure the length of all lines and drop lines that are less than a certain length. That would remove segments that perhaps are not particularly useful, but in this scenario it wouldn't work.

You could also measure the bearing or angle of the segment. It looks like that's what you're saying here, that the line ought to be ignored because it's at an angle to the simplified junction layout. The HorizontalAngleCalculator from the FME Hub will do the measuring part for you.

But then FME would have to know that the segment's angle is different to the main network. Maybe you could use the NeighborFinder to find the nearest lines to each point, and from there figure out which is at the correct azimuth/bearing?

Or maybe... use the NeighborFinder on each line to find its closest other lines. If a line is, say, 40-50 degrees different the lines it connects to, then it should be removed.

The TopologyBuilder transformer may also help to provide this information.

Anyway, I'm afraid that's the best I have. In short, try to measure the azimuth and then compare neighboring segments to see if they have a matching bearing or not. but exactly how you do that depends on the exact criteria for a line needing to be discarded.

Comment: Hello,

First of all thank you for these tips I learned a lot of things, in fact to explain to you, the idea was to snap these GPS points on the road network, and normally if we apply the normal snapper it will do the objective, but there are certain points which will be snapped on the wrong segment, in particular the point which has labels 70, and to let you know the labels are used to know the route made (10.20 ........ 70.80 ...), so we are sure that point 70 should be snapped on segment 1, and not 2. I tried a lot of methods but unfortunately I did not succeed.

Comment: Link of image: link : https://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=21/27/bxaq.png

Comment: @Mostafa if you know where it should be snapped, and both the to be snapped to features and the to be snapped features share an id, you can set this as Group By in the AnchoredSnapper, which solves your issue?

Comment: Oh yes, I can see why that point ought to be snapped to segment 1, but it's hard to translate what the human brain can see into a rule that FME can follow. As @nielsgerrits mentions, maybe the group-by will help? If segment 1 has an attribute RoadType = Main and segment 2 is RoadType = Connector, then it would be a lot easier to handle.